# Turn off power notification sound on LG G2

Tags: audio, system, lg-g2

I've got an LG G2 (Verizon) and I'd like to turn off all the notification sounds for when I plug in my phone, when I unplug it, and when it gets to full power.

I've turned the system notification volume setting to zero, but I still hear these sounds.

What am I missing?

Comment: Tried going to settings > Sound and see if there is an option for this?
There might be a similar setting in settings > Battery.

Comment: I checked both places and there isn't anything. S'why I asked here. :)